# C# is there ever a reason to use ArrayList instead of List<T> anymore?

Tags: c#, list, arraylist

The title pretty much sums it up. Now that we have `List<T>`'s why would anyone want to use an `ArrayList` instead? The only reason I can think of is if you are forced to use an old version of .NET before `List<T>` was implemented?

Comment: I suppose if you wanted to have a list of various, unrelated types.

Comment: @John: In which case I'd prefer to use `List<object>` for the sake of consistency.

Comment: Various, unrelated types could go into List<object>

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# When should I use List and when should I use arraylist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725459/c-when-should-i-use-list-and-when-should-i-use-arraylist)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you said, if for some reason you are stuck with .Net 1.1 then you don't have a choice.

Your question seems to indicate that there is a choice. So then there is no reason to user`ArrayList`. Anything that `ArrayList` can do, `List<T>` can do as well, if not better.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer, no. ArrayList was from when .NET didn't support generics. List is the more flexible (generic) way to handle lists. In fact, I don't think Silverlight even supports ArrayLists at all.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList is mostly for backward compatibility. In a project when there is a deadline, you may have the time to convert everything from ArrayList to generic List.

Another reason is that you may be using a library that is written in .NET 1.1. So you may force to use ArrayList in your code, and most likely convert it to a generic List for easy coding.

However, there are some differences and you may want to read this:
[.NET: ArrayList vs List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365482/net-arraylist-vs-list)

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself: backwards compatibility. There's no use for it any more, but it clearly can't be removed from the BCL as it'd break existing code that for whatever reason must be compiled against .NET 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

The ***only*** time I've ever used an ArrayList since .Net 2.0 was for use with the built-in My.Settings feature in vb.net, and I've since learned I probably could have shoehorned a generic list in there.