# using winforms (C#) duplicate a row of the form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to design a winform. The initial design has several rows, each with a label, a number entry box input, and an output text box. I have got the first row working.

Now I want to programmatically duplicate this row, several times. I have put the components into a panel (an container, with no frame). I was then hoping to clone this panel, and its content, set a now location, and label text for each.

I could probably workout how to do it all programmatically. However I want to layout the header and the first row, with the layout tool.

Am I going about this in a good way? What am I missing.

Comment: I think you mean "programmatically"

Comment: You're missing a grid.

Comment: Sound like you want a `UserControl`. It has full designer support and on the form it acts like a single control.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb auto-correct is evil (I did not even know, it was switched on).

Comment: @LarsTech any more info would be appreciated.

Comment: @C.evenhuis any more info would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a DataGridView for this instead of trying to recreate a grid?

Comment: @LarsTech ah, so tell me more about DataGridView.

Comment: I think you can do some study on [datagridview](https://www.google.com/search?q=datagridview+example+c%23&oq=datagridview+example+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.14193j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor there are a lot of resources about UserControls, my explanation isn't going to be as good as those. Take a look at for instance https://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_user_controls.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can proceed with this idea by cloning the main control and all of its child controls.

Here is a sample code for that:

```
namespace CloneAControl
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int yValue = 50;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Panel ctrl = panel1.Clone();
            //Control ctrl = ControlFactory.CloneCtrl(this.panel1);

            this.Controls.Add(ctrl);
            //ctrl.Text = "created by clone";
            ctrl.SetBounds(ctrl.Bounds.X, ctrl.Bounds.Y + yValue,
                           ctrl.Bounds.Width, ctrl.Bounds.Height);
            yValue = yValue + 50;
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
            ctrl.Show();
        }
    }

    public static class ControlExtensions
    {
        public static T Clone<T>(this T controlToClone)
            where T : Control
        {
            PropertyInfo[] controlProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            T instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

            foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in controlProperties)
            {
                if (propInfo.CanWrite)
                {
                    if (propInfo.Name != "WindowTarget")
                        propInfo.SetValue(instance, propInfo.GetValue(controlToClone, null), null);
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 approaches for this :

1. **The naive approach :**

Which is to create the panels in the design view and hide them except the first one, and programmatically you can show and hide them as you want.

**-Disatvantages :**

1. The number of panels you want to show is going to be **fixed (limited)**.
2. You are not using the power of [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) at all.

---

---

2. **The better approach :**

Which is to create an array of the panels (rows) in your case, to store the panels and all of its child controls.

**-Disatvantage :**

1. The number of panels you want to show is **still** going to be **fixed (limited)**.

**-To solve this problem :**

Look for the terms [Data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128636/net-data-structures-arraylist-list-hashtable-dictionary-sortedlist-sorted), [Generics](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_generics.htm).

`List` would be good choice in your case.

**Hope that was useful.**

Comment: An ArrayList?  No.  [Always prefer a List<T> to an ArrayList.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4251166/719186)

Comment: @LarsTech You're right.. Thanks for mentioning that.. Answer update 