# Which one is faster List<T> or ArrayList<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET: ArrayList vs List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365482/net-arraylist-vs-list)

Hello,

I searched around the web and find my conflicting answers and so far unclear as to,
Which one is faster `List<T> or ArrayList<T>` and what is the reason?

I am guessing `List<T>` should be faster but not sure as in this specific case even `ArrayList<T>` also is marked as a generic type.

Much Thanks,
Mani

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to profile?

Comment: I don't know of any `ArrayList<T>`. Where do you see that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365482/net-arraylist-vs-list

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I made this for you.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        Console.WriteLine("Adding a million 32bit integers");

        sw.Start();
        List<int> listA = new List<int>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            listA.Add(i);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("List<int> took {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();

        sw.Start();
        List<object> listB = new List<object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            listB.Add(i);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("List<object> took {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();

        sw.Start();
        ArrayList listC = new ArrayList();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            listC.Add(i);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("ArrayList took {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();

        Console.WriteLine("\n Inserting 1000 values");
        //Gen list of random numbers
        Random rand = new Random(12345);
        int[] insertlocs = new int[1000];
        for (int i = 0; i < insertlocs.Length; i++)
            insertlocs[i] = rand.Next(1, 999999);

        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < insertlocs.Length; i++)
        {
            listA.Insert(insertlocs[i], i);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("List<int> took {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();

        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < insertlocs.Length; i++)
        {
            listB.Insert(insertlocs[i], i);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("List<object> took {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();

        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < insertlocs.Length; i++)
        {
            listC.Insert(insertlocs[i], i);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("ArrayList took {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

On my comp, `List<int>` took 13ms, `List<object>` took 69ms, `ArrayList` took 40ms.

So there you have it, for reference types ArrayList is faster. But for value types you should obviously use List

EDIT: Testing insert performance too, `List<int>` took 255ms, `List<object>` took 723ms, `ArrayList` took 397ms. ArrayList *with boxing* is almost on par with List without boxing!

Comment: Try adding `new Object()` to `ListB` to avoid boxing (and note there is a typo: in 2nd test you're using `ListA` in the loop).

Comment: I fixed the typo before posting my results but after copying the code, so it's still valid, but thanks for pointing it out. What do you mean? Values are boxed in both List<object> and ArrayList, casting the ints to objects doesn't change performance at all.

Comment: One interesting thing is if you size the collections on creation List<T> gets faster and ArrayList gets slower, at least on my machine.

Comment: Wow, significantly too! I'm going to take a peek at the classes to see what they do differently.

Comment: @Hannesh: Indeed value types are boxed when added to both `List<Object>` and `ArrayList`, but then what are you comparing? One wouldn't use `List<Object>` except to be homogeneous. Two of the benefits of generic types are avoiding boxing and being typesafe.

Comment: It's true that one wouldn't use List<object> but one would use List<SomeClass>. By testing List<object> we can properly compare the speed of ArrayList and List when adding refernce types since the boxing overhead is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 13):

I suppose you meant `List<T>` and `ArrayList`.

you should be using `List<T>` and not `ArrayList` because it doesn't have all the boxing\un-boxing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it depends, are you talking about lookups, inserts, etc?

Comment: +1 they both have their own pros and cons