# Type casting Strings

Tags: arrays, vb.net, excel

I am using an array list to store my strings. However when I run the program it throws an error : Conversion from type 'String()' to type 'String" is not valid. I am sure I am missing something simple. I thought an ArrayList was a list of objects and that it could be anything that I was sent to the array. e.g. Strings in, Strings out. Here is the code that I am working with.

```
   Dim tempString As New ArrayList()

     For Each s As String In tempString
            Dim sAry As String() = bufString.Split(New Char() {ChrW(2)})
            For i As Int16 = 1 To sAry.Length
                xlCells(CurrentRow, i).Value = sAry(i - 1).ToString()
            Next
        Next
```

I also have come to understand that ArrayList has depreciated, should I be using something else?

Comment: Where is `bufString` declared?

Comment: you arent using the strings in tempString anywhere...`For Each s in  TempString` but s is not used in the loop.  Turn on Option Strict as well. A `List(of String)` would be a good replacement for the ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before jumping into your case quickly please give a look into other great answers

> [What's Wrong with an ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326599/whats-wrong-with-an-arraylist)
>
> [.NET: ArrayList vs List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365482/net-arraylist-vs-list)

and you can google to know more in this regard...

For known typed collection it is not good to use ArrayLists.
For your case I would suggest generic List collection(List is much more efficient in terms of memory usage)
You can see my below test case for you:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim tempList As New List(Of String) 'Consider List Rather ArrayList as you knw your requirement for Strings collection
    tempList.Add("string1string2string3string4") 'for testing purpose I've joined "string1, string2, string3 & string4" with ChrW(2) unicode character

    For Each s As String In tempList
        Dim sAry As String() = s.Split(New Char() {ChrW(2)})
        For i As Int16 = 1 To sAry.Length
            'xlCells(CurrentRow, i).Value = sAry(i - 1).ToString()
            Console.WriteLine(sAry(i - 1).ToString())
        Next
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```